# Why is Kitkat process stats value vary a lot wrt MAT

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to analyse my Apps memory usage,

I tried to get MAT hprof dumps consecutively for a 5 min period of time and saw the heap size max reach 40MB, after the app was put in background its Heap Size came to ~ 37MB, and allocated was 23MB

But if I go to process stats on Kitkat, Average memory usage is showing 58MB and peak as 59MB, Even Settings -> Application Manager -> Running

Can some one help me understand why such big disconnect and how can I debug where the memory is with held. I thought MAT was the best tool for this.
i expect my App to be under 50MBs and in normal scenario should be in 20-30MBs, but since Running tab shows 59MB am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two Android OS versions on different phones by any chance?

If so there's a very good chance that the discrepancy in memory is not the OS, but simply the DPI of the screen. Higher screen DPI requires much larger assets (bitmaps) to be stored in memory which would reflect what you're seeing.

Even if you have same image stored in your `drawable/` folder displayed on both phones, Android will scale it for your screensize, and so at runtime, the same image will take different amounts of memory on both phones.

Run the emulator with both Kitkat and an earlier version of Android with the same DPI screen size, and you should see much more similar memory usage with your app.

Comment: Just to clarify I have run MAT on same app isntance and on same device. bascially say i took hprof dump at :9:05am, 9:10 am and had check App Manager -> Running , Proc Stats at ~9:05:25 , 9:10:25 basically few secs after the dump.